Vertical fancyapp carousel doesn't work, any tips on how to solve this?
I'm building a carousel a little different than usual, for this to be possible, I need it to be vertical because of its animations, but before building anything else, fancyapp's carousel module for some reason can't handle the carousel vertical. I've tried different ways to pull this vertical carousel, but either it doesn't even hold the carousel or it pulls horizontally, any tips on how to solve this?
https://codepen.io/Erick-Moura-Ruiz-Guedes-Cardoso/pen/oNOJrZJ
HTML
<!-- Fancybox Carrossel -->
<script src="https://twist-dev.com/modelo/wp-includes/js/carousel/carousel.umd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://twist-dev.com/modelo/wp-includes/js/carousel/carousel.css"/>   

<div id="Carrossel-falso" class="hero">
        <div class="hero-wrap">
            <div class="hero__left col">
                <h1>NOSSOS NÚMEROS</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="hero__right col">
                <div class="hero__items f-carousel is-vertical is-rtl">
                    <div class="hero__item">
                        <div class="item__cost">600 km</div>  
                        <div class="item__name">de barreiras instaladas</div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="hero__item">
                        <div class="item__cost">28 cidades</div>  
                        <div class="item__name">onde produziu barreiras</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hero__item">
                        <div class="item__cost">58 rodovias</div>  
                        <div class="item__name">mais seguras graças as nossas barreiras</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hero__item">
                        <div class="item__cost">30 empresas</div>  
                        <div class="item__name">que optaram pela Serguvia</div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="teste"> 

</div>

CSS
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #555;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Estilizando a barra de rolagem */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;  /* Oculta a barra de rolagem no Chrome/Safari */
}

/* Estilizando a alça (thumb) da barra de rolagem */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;  /* Torna a alça (thumb) invisível */
}

.hero {
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: #000a;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

.hero-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000a;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
}

.hero__left {
  padding: 25px;
}

.item__name {
  font-size: 20px; 
  width: 200px; 
}

.hero__left h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 300px;
}

.hero__right {
  position: sticky !important;
  right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.hero__item {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #111;
  border: 4px solid #333;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.hero__item:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero__item.active {
  border: 4px solid #0047ffaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #0332ad;
}

.teste{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  
}


JS
var carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll('#Carrossel-falso .hero__item');
    carouselItems.forEach(function(item) {
        item.classList.add('f-carousel__slide');
    });

  const container = document.querySelector("#Carrossel-falso .f-carousel");
    if (container) {
        var options = {
            transitionEffect: "vertical",
            Dots: false,
            Navigation: true,
            infinite: false,
            axis: "y",
            slidesPerPage: "1",
        };
      
        new Carousel(container, options);
    }


Classes and options defines
I need to do something similar to this, I already had an idea of ​​the code for the scroll to click on next and prev, but without the vertical carousel the animation wouldn't be good
example
Any tips on how to solve this.

Set the height of the container to less than the height of the content, for example:
.hero__items {
  height: 100px;
}

See https://fancyapps.com/carousel/getting-started/#add-markup
